Prototype is showing multiple times
I have implemented inheritance as below:
    class Animal {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        speak() {
            console.log(${this.name} is making noise.);
        }
    }

    class Dog extends Animal {
        constructor(name, breed) {
            super(name);
            this.breed = breed;
        }
    }

    const dog = new Dog("Rex", "German Shepherd");
    console.log(dog);


Why Animal prototype is showing multiple times in console.log()?


Because Dog.prototype.constructor === Dog. It doesn't even need to inherit from Animal for that, it's the default of how the .constructor property is set up
